# How to pass selinux error when executing netstat via script in keepalived?

Tags: linux, keepalived

Is there a way to pass selinux security when executing netstat command in  keepalived?
I get below message when I execute netstat in vrrp_scrpt of keepalived.
My goal is to monitor udp/2048 change Master and Backup when the port is down.

```
Nov 24 02:36:25 server1 setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/netstat from using the getattr access on a process. For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l 09a907de-253e-4c61-8506-1c247c1daf11
Nov 24 02:36:25 server1 python: SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/netstat from using the getattr access on a process.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that netstat should be allowed getattr access on processes labeled tuned_t by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# grep netstat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol#012# semodule -i mypol.pp#012
```

My environement is below.

```
[root@server230 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
[root@server230 ~]# rpm -qa | grep keepalived
keepalived-1.2.13-8.el7.x86_64
```

My keepalived config is below.

```
global_defs {
   notification_email {
     root@localhost.localdomain
   }
   notification_email_from root@localhost.localdomain
   smtp_server 127.0.0.1
   smtp_connect_timeout 60
}

vrrp_script chk_logstash {
  script "netstat -atunp | grep 2048 &>/dev/null"
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
}

vrrp_instance RH_1 {
    state MASTER 
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 50
    priority 10
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.11.250/24
    }

    track_script {
      chk_logstash
    }
}
```

netstat and keepalived process has below selinux context

```
[root@server230 ~]# ls -lZ /usr/bin/netstat 
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/bin/netstat
[root@server230 ~]# ps -eZ | grep keepalived
system_u:system_r:keepalived_t:s0 2913 ?       00:00:00 keepalived
system_u:system_r:keepalived_t:s0 2914 ?       00:00:00 keepalived
system_u:system_r:keepalived_t:s0 2915 ?       00:00:00 keepalived
system_u:system_r:keepalived_t:s0 4609 ?       00:00:00 keepalived
```

Comment: First, update the system. There have been numerous fixes to SELinux policy in the two years since you last updated this system.

Comment: I have updated to RHEL 7.3 using yum update but error is still occuring.